# How to filter collection rows while using .each() in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I want to filter this `$authors` collection.

```
$authors = Author::get();
```

In my view, I need to show how many books an author is related.
I use .each() to merge the `count` to `$authors` and return it to where it was called.

```
return $authors->each(function($author, $key){

            $author->count = Author::findOrFail($author->id)->books()->count();

        });
```

Question is "How can I remove/filter if an author have not wrriten any of a book(count <= 0)?"

I tried this is and it failed.

```
return $authors->each(function($author, $key){

                $author->count = Author::findOrFail($author->id)->books()->count();
               $author->filter(function($author, $key){
                    return $author->count <= 0;
               })

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) to avoid [N+1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and performance problems:

```
$authors = Author::withCount('books')->get();
```

In a Blade view, you'll be able to do:

```
$author->books_count
```

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the `withCount` method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: ok...I just forgot some code in my question(updated for now).

Comment: It's a good information. But how can I remove/filter rows if counted value is zero.

Comment: @HeinHtutAung just add simple conditional, like `@if ($author->books_count)` to check if author has any books. Or you can skip loading authors without books with `->has('books')`. If you want to filter the data, use the `filter()` method.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyMezenin! It works with `withCount()` and `filter()` .